# Why does casting from byte to sbyte give a wrong value for optimized code?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

The problem can be reproduced with the following code sample, having NUnit 3 installed.

```
[TestFixture]
public class SByteFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var data = new byte[] { 0xFF };

        sbyte x = -128;
        data[0] = (byte) x;
        byte b1 = data[0];
        var b2 = (sbyte) b1;
        Assert.AreEqual(b1.ToString(), "128");
        Assert.AreEqual(b2.ToString(), "-128");
    }
}
```

1. The project should be a ***class library*** because in a ***console application*** it's not reproducible.
2. Should have optimization enabled, i.e. the following setting in the csproj file:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
       <Optimize>true</Optimize>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

The test **passes** when **Optimize is false**, but it **fails** when **Optimize is true** (`b2.ToString()` gives `"128"`).

This can be seen using **ReSharper** for running the test or **NUnitConsole**, not reproducible with **VS Test Explorer**.

How can this be explained?

Comment: This bug is specific to the 64-bit jitter with the optimizer enabled, probably why it seemed hard to repro.  I've seen this go wrong before, this part of the optimizer is brittle.  It is the (sbyte) cast that produces wrong code, it *should* use the MOVSX processor instruction (signed extension from byte to int) but uses MOVZX.  The incorrect zero-extension produces a positive number.  Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues) to make them aware of it.

Comment: Can someone show this question to new users as an example of how to write a question, pleaze thankz

Comment: @HansPassant Sounds like an answer ;)

Comment: It's always fun to find a JIT bug :)

Answer (score 1):

As @HansPassant suggested, I've reported this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/20439), and it seems to be a confirmed bug.

Here's a quote on this issue from [mikedn](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/20439#issuecomment-430335169)

> The fact that you can reproduce in a class library and not a console
>   application might mean that you're using .NET Framework and not .NET
>   Core. In .NET Framework console apps default to 32 bit so they use the
>   legacy JIT32, not RyuJIT. 64 bit .NET Framework apps use RyuJIT but
>   it's typically an older version than the one used by .NET Core.
>
> I can reproduce this issue using 64 bit .NET Framework 4.7.2 but not
>   the current master version of .NET Core. It can be reproduce using
>   .NET Core 2.1 so it's likely that this was already fixed in master.